# How to make all backgrounds have a background-size: cover?

Tags: html, css

On my body, I have 3 images displayed horizontally.

Each image takes up 33% width.

Together, these 3 images take up the entire webpage.

How can I make these 3 images have a background size of cover, so their aspect ratio's are maintained?

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1546166/pexels-photo-1546166.jpeg),
                      url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/87223/pexels-photo-87223.jpeg),
                      url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/280221/pexels-photo-280221.jpeg);

    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left, center, right;
    background-size: 33% 100%, 34% 100%, 33% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to break them up so that it's one background per element.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Ouroborus.

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to look up and experiment with, there is *no way* to have them individually set to cover. 
I do however, have a work around!

```css
body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0px;
}

#back1,#back2,#back3{
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: calc(100%/3);
      height: 100vh;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
}
  
#back1{background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1546166/pexels-photo-1546166.jpeg);}
#back2{background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/87223/pexels-photo-87223.jpeg);left:calc(100%/3);}
#back3{background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/280221/pexels-photo-280221.jpeg);left:calc(200%/3);}

h1{margin-top: 0px;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="back1"></div>
  <div id="back2"></div>
  <div id="back3"></div>
  <h1>This text will start at the top left like it would otherwise.</h1>
</body>
```

*Everything below #back3 is fair game to put whatever.*

***Things to note about my solution:***

The `z-index: -1;` is for making the text visible, otherwise it will be behind each **"back-div"**.

The `margin-top:0px` on the **h1** element is so that there is no white space at the top. If you take it off, it will move each **back-div** down as much as h1's top margin. If you take it off, but then use `top:0px` on each **back-div**, the blank space will be at the bottom. *Text margins like to be funky around absolute-positioned elements. So the best way to fix the problem child (any text element early in the `<body>`) is a margin adjustment.* Hope this helps!